# thresholding grayscale image without converting binary image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, grayscale, threshold

I would like to know how can ı achieve thresholding based on grayscale intensity by not converting it to binary image. As an example, below 50 intensity will be 0 while 50-255 intensity values remain the same(in Matlab).

Answer (score 3):

Check the following...

Read sample image:

```
I = imread('cameraman.tif');
```

Set all values below 50 to zero.

```
I(I < 50) = 0;
```